# Height of the div is not being auto

Tags: html, css, jcrop

I have the following code in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ex34E/1/) fiddle , I want the height of the profile_window_content to be more than the height of the image in jcrop-tracker.Height of div is set to auto , then why it is not greater than image height. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Floated content is supposed to fall out of the bottom of containers](http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/).

[Set overflow to hidden if you want to cause containers to wrap floated elements anyway](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59).